# Retrieve value from input and post it in the same PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to read the value that is in the input box and based on that, create (with PHP in the same file) some dropdown boxes. After trying several hours I can't find a way to do this.

The HTML Input Field

```
<input type="text" onblur="sendData(this.value)" name="ingr_count" id="ingr_count" pattern="\d*" />
```

I have this JS/AJAX to read the value and post it in the PHP

```
function sendData(obj) {
            var xmlhttp;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    alert(obj);
                    // Do stuff when script returns
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("POST","script.php?count=" + obj.value + "&t="+Math.random(),true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

I also have this PHP to read the value

```
$src1= $_POST['count'];  
echo $src1;
```

Commenting out everything bellow 
    var xmlhttp; 
and alerting the obj will alert the obj but if I uncomment it won't even alert the value! :O .

Comment: `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: I dont think this is relevant. The POST read will be done from the value that the ajax has sent and its 

    xmlhttp.open("POST","**script.php?count**"=" + obj.value + "&t="+Math.random(),true");

Comment: @Musa I fixed the fault I have in the xmlhttp.open with the = .  I used name and id for some testing I did in the past.

Comment: You're missing a quote in `xmlhttp.open("POST","script.php?count=" + obj.value + "&t="+Math.random(),true");` or one too many. Noticed Stack's syntax highlighting? There are seven, therefore a quote mismatch. So, check the one that used to work *in the past*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh damned my eyes, is from the too many hours on this project. Didn't even see that. Thanks a lot for the input. Although I fixed it and the alerts are firing I can't read the value with the PHP code. I would like to notice that the PHP and the AJAX is in the same page.

Comment: Just to test, can you rename these `name="ingr_count" id="ingr_count"` to `name="count" id="count"` - it's just a hunch.

Comment: I did but nothing changed. I think I am doing a really stupid question. But shouldn't PHP rerun(refresh) when I pass the value to the $src1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comments of @Mura and @Fred-ii- I managed to complete my AJAX code. The problem was that when I recieved the value I couldn't use it in PHP. So when I read the value on AJAX I created a cookie and stored the input box value inside and after that I refresh the content of the PHP. So the final code is something like the below.

The HTML

```
<input type="text" onblur="sendData(this.value)" name="ingr_count" id="ingr_count" pattern="\d*" />
```

The JS/AJAX

```
function sendData(obj) {
            var xmlhttp;

             alert (obj);
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    alert(obj);
                    // Do stuff when script returns
                }
            }


            document.cookie="count="+ obj;
            alert (obj);
            var x = document.cookie;
            alert (x);
            $("#main").load("script.php");

        }
```

The PHP

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["count"])){

 $src1= $_COOKIE["count"];

   echo $src1;

 setcookie('count', '', time()-300); 
} else { do whatever you want   }
```